# JQuery selecting only the element inside the selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having problem selecting the right element on a form

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wpcf7-submit").click(function () {
        if($('.errorName').length > 0){
            return false;
        }
    });

    var selectorArray = [$('input[name="name"]'), $('input[name="Company"]')];
    $.each(selectorArray, function(){
      $(this).on('blur',function(){
        if($('.errorName').length == 0 && (($(this).val().length < 4  && $(this).val().length != 0) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test($(this).val()) == false))
        {
            $(this).after('<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip errorName" role="alert">Field is not right.</span>');
        }
        else
        {           
            if($(this).val().length > 3 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test($(this).val()) == true) 
            { 
               $(this).find('.errorName').remove();
            }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to check, on unfocus, if what the user has input is good for a couple of fields inside the form, else an error message appears. Unfortunately, I can't seem to remove the error message, and this code stucks that message on the first field the user inputs wrong. After that, it won't come off even if the input typed after the first unfocus satisfies the conditions.

I'm testing on a simple form with 2 text inputs and 1 submit. Without the remove part, I can see both messages being displayed and on

```
$(this).find('errorName').first().remove();
```

It's the second element that gets stuck with the error message.

Comment: In your blur handler, `$('.errorName').length == 0` should probably be `$(this).find('.errorName').length == 0` — it’s checking whether *any* field has an error message, rather than checking the field you’re looking at.

Comment: Input elements don't have children, therefore `$(this).find('.errorName')` is guaranteed to find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're placing the errorName span after the input element, so you need to look for a sibling instead. You can use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) for this.

```
$(this).next('.errorName').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I ended having to change the condition to next() as well because then the error messages would keep on stacking if I still used .find there